# Parenthesis Powershell functions

Tags: function, powershell

How to call function using parameters in powershell with parenthesis.

I have as example this function

```
function Greet([string]$name , [int]$times)
{
    for ([int]$i = 1; $i -le $times;$i++)
    {
        Write-Host Hiiii $name
    }
}
```

If I call the functions using
`Greet Ricardo 5` or `Greet "Ricardo" 5` works.
But when I use `Greet ("Ricardo",5)` or `Greet("Ricardo" ; 5)` It fails.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with no parenthesis?

Comment: Nothing. I am wondering how they create functions (cmd-lets) that use parenthesis

Comment: For eexample `$ACL.SetAccessRule $Rule` doesn't work without parenthesis.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Functions behaves like cmdlets.  That is, you don't type dir(c:\temp).  Functions likewise take parameters as space separated and like cmdlets, support positional, named and optional parameters e.g.:

```
Greet Recardo 5
Greet -times 5 -name Ricardo
```

PowerShell uses () to allow you to specify expressions like so:

```
function Greet([string[]]$names, [int]$times=5) {
    foreach ($name in $names) {
        1..$times | Foreach {"Hi $name"}
    }
}

Greet Ricardo (1+4)

Great Ricardo    # Note that $times defaults to 5
```

You can also specify arrays simple by using a comma separated list e.g.:

```
Greet Ricardo,Lucy,Ethyl (6-1)
```

So when you pass in something like `("Ricardo",5)` that is evaluated as a single parameter value that is an array containing two elements `"Ricardo"` and `5`. That would be passed to the `$name` parameter but then there would be no value for the `$times` parameter.

The only time you use a parenthesized parameter list is when calling .NET methods e.g.:

```
"Hello World".Substring(6, 3)
```