# Print a value from a hashtable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code example. I am just trying to print the value from a hashtable key.

```
function New-Article()
{
  param ($volume, $issue, $title)

  $article = @{}
  $article.volume = $volume
  $article.issue = $issue
  $article.title = $title

  return $article
}

$article = New-Article(1, 2, "Article Title")
Write-Host "Article title: $article.title" # Output = Article title: System.Collections.Hashtable.title
Write-Host "Article title: $($article.title)" # Output = Article title: 
Write-Host "Article volume: $($article.volume)" # Output = Article volume: 1 2 Article Title

$article = New-Article 1, 2, "Article Title"
Write-Host "Article title: $($article.title)" # Output = Article title:
```

**Edit** added a line to test what is mentioned in the possible duplicate (relating to properties, not hashtables)

**Edit** Added more examples based on comments and answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you use an object's property in a double-quoted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145704/how-can-you-use-an-objects-property-in-a-double-quoted-string)

Comment: According to that answer, I can add `$()` around the variable to print (for properties anyway), that resulted in an empty string when used with a hashtable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11060833

Comment: Not sure how that is supposed to be relevant

Comment: Output: `Article volume: 1 2 Article Title`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 problems. In addition to enclosing the hashtable property access expression in a $(), you are invoking the function incorrectly. In powershell, arguments are passed to a function separated by spaces, with no brackets:

```
function New-Article()
{
  param ($volume, $issue, $title)

  $article = @{}
  $article.volume = $volume
  $article.issue = $issue
  $article.title = $title

  return $article
}

$article = New-Article 1 2 "Article Title"
Write-Host "Article title: $($article.title)"
```

Comment: When I removed the parenthesis from the call to `New-Article`, it resulted in the same output

Comment: remove the commas too, the commas tell powershell to create an array.